# Telerik: Unable to get value of property 'open': Object is null or undefined

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I've got a web site that uses Telerik controls. I have an editing form that opens in a RadWindow. This functionality exists on two separate pages one it works perfectly the second the RadWindow never opens. I've stared and stared at the two pages trying to figure out where I went wrong but I cannot figure it out.

**Errors:**

1.) Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd:3

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'control' of undefined
```

2.) Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd:11319

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'open' of undefined
```

This one actually has some legible code.

```
window.radopen=function(b,a){var c=GetRadWindowManager();
return c.open(b,a);//Error Here
```

**Page RadWindow Components:**

```
 <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager2" runat="server" Modal="true" ShowContentDuringLoad="false">
    <Windows>
        <telerik:RadWindow runat="server" ID="rwEditCust" Width="500px" Height="500px" Title="Edit Cust" Modal="true" ReloadOnShow="true"></telerik:RadWindow>
    </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>


<telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="rampCustList" runat="server"> 
 <AjaxSettings>
    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rampCustList">
        <UpdatedControls>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rgCustList" />
        </UpdatedControls>
    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
</AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>

<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowEditCust(id) {
      alert("Test");
      window.radopen("EditCust.aspx?A=E&id=" + id, "rwEditCust");
      return false;
    }

    function refreshGrid(arg) {
      var ajaxManager = $find("<%= RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).ClientID %>");
      ajaxManager.ajaxRequest();
    }

</script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

Conventional wisdom would say that this has to be an issue with this view page bc I'm not getting any errors in my code behind page. All the components seem to be loading correctly otherwise my other page would break as well. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Udpate**

<del>In my design view I get an error on my radajaxmanagerproxy that it's missing a runat=server but it does have that attribute.</del>

Resolved the above error. No effect on the primary issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out a commented piece of code in my view was causing the error. Removed commented code and issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it turned out I misplaced `<telerik:RadWindow` outside `<form runat="server"></form>` tag

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The `radopen` function requires the `RadWindowManager` to exist on the page, even though you do not explicitly reference it in your code. By adding the following code snippets I could solve the issue.

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server"></telerik:RadWindowManager>
```